# VBScript to Refresh Excel Data Connections (Trouble with Office 365)

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vbscript

I have a large Excel file that uses PowerPivot to connect to several external data sources. The Excel file is stored in a SharePoint folder. I would like to be able to refresh the connections automatically overnight. To do this, I am using Windows Task Scheduler to trigger a VBScript each day at 2AM.

Previously, I had the script run a macro within the workbook to refresh all. This worked successfully until my organization recently updated to Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus. I am now struggling with the new read-only default setting for SharePoint. Following the update, whenever I open an Excel file from SharePoint, I see a yellow bar reading "Read-Only: We opened this workbook read-only from the server. Edit Workbook". When working with files manually, this has to be clicked before changes can be saved. I tried to research the programmatic workaround for this and found the recommendation to use the method .LockServerFile.

To streamline the trouble-shooting, I have tried to move the entire action into the VBScript script, rather than running a macro within the workbook. My code is below.

When I watch the process, the yellow "Read-Only" bar appears to pop up immediately before the save. I can run the process once with no apparent errors, but if I then manually open the file, I don't see the option to "Edit Workbook". If I manually change the file, save, and then run the script again, I get the error 800A03EC.

It seems that somehow the script is failing to correctly "release" the lock on the server file after it finishes.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("[[The Sharepoint Path]]")
objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Visible = True

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.LockServerFile

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.EnableConnections

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("P2").Value = Date

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close  false

objExcel.Application.Quit

set objworkbook = Nothing
set objExcel = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```